# Does snapd provide a way to fix a broken package?

Tags: package-management, snap

`snap` stores all of its packages - including core dependencies such as `bare` and `core` as well as every software package as single SquashFS `.snap` files and then mounts these files (usually in `/snap/` directory) in order to access the contents. This is how it looks in action (output of `mount | grep snap`):

```
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_17029.snap on /snap/snapd/17029 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap on /snap/bare/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/prusa-slicer_60.snap on /snap/prusa-slicer/60 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
```

`snap` also does not have a command for reinstalling the package like, for example, `apt reinstall`. In order to do a reinstall one needs to remove the package and install it again.

Given these two properties, it is possible to break all of the software installed via `snap` by simply corrupting a SquashFS file containing some of the core dependencies.

It's exactly what happened to me yesterday - I couldn't run any software that has been installed using `snap`. Every attempt ended up in exactly the same stacktrace:

```
unexpected fault address 0x6208c0
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0x6208c0 pc=0x6208c0]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw(0x85ef48, 0x5)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:774 +0x72 fp=0xc0000dde38 sp=0xc0000dde08 pc=0x42e582
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:391 +0x455 fp=0xc0000dde68 sp=0xc0000dde38 pc=0x4426c5
compress/bzip2.init.0()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/compress/bzip2/bzip2.go:479 fp=0xc0000dde70 sp=0xc0000dde68 pc=0x6208c0
runtime.doInit(0xd0c400)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5222 +0x8a fp=0xc0000ddea0 sp=0xc0000dde70 pc=0x43bf1a
runtime.doInit(0xd11da0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc0000dded0 sp=0xc0000ddea0 pc=0x43bee7
runtime.doInit(0xd12160)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc0000ddf00 sp=0xc0000dded0 pc=0x43bee7
runtime.doInit(0xd117e0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc0000ddf30 sp=0xc0000ddf00 pc=0x43bee7
runtime.doInit(0xd0fdc0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc0000ddf60 sp=0xc0000ddf30 pc=0x43bee7
runtime.main()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:190 +0x1da fp=0xc0000ddfe0 sp=0xc0000ddf60 pc=0x42feda
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 +0x1 fp=0xc0000ddfe8 sp=0xc0000ddfe0 pc=0x45a541
snap-update-ns failed with code 2
```

Kernel log contained some more hints:

```
[19136.436337] SQUASHFS error: xz decompression failed, data probably corrupt
[19136.436339] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0xfbf09
[19136.436361] SQUASHFS error: xz decompression failed, data probably corrupt
[19136.436362] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0xfbf09
```

It was more or less clear to me that one of the core snaps must have been somehow damaged.

The question is, **how to fix such an issue in an elegant way?** There's no easy way to find which file has been corrupted and even if I'd have found that - snap provides no option to reinstall a package other that removing and installing it again.

Because of that, the only solution I see is removing all packages and installing them again - and this is what I ended up doing. Isn't there any other, less invasive option?

In order to replicate this issue, one can simply put random data in one of the core snaps - making it unreadable (backup the file first):

`head -c 50M </dev/urandom > /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1623.snap`

Comment: Could you maybe ask a clear question, I can not tell what you are asking. Also nothing in the question body seems to match the title.

Comment: @David Added introduction on how snap manages packages internally.